# How to fix [Object object] response when getting the sum of array values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuetify.js

Im trying to build a scored survey with vuejs and vuetify. Im using a stepper component along with selects to get answers from a user. Depending on the user's score, a service package is recommended at the end.

If user score is less than 25, essentials package is recommended.
If the user score is between 25 and 50, the pro package is recommended.
If the user score is 50 or above, the premium package is recommended.

Ive so far been able to push all answers into an empty array named "questionAnswer". I have an attribute called questionId ('i') which contains the score for the given answer.

**When I try to sum the attributes, I get the following response: [Object object][Object object][Object object][Object object][Object object][Object object]**

Here is the response in the console, first block is the values of questionId, second block is the response when I try to sum the array values.
[image]

response (No JSON parse)
[image]

This is my code inside the script tag, each question has its own array of responses. The items1 through items 7 arrays contain the responses, which are pushed to a new array called questionAnswer.

```
export default {
data () {
  return {
    e1: 1,
    steps: 8,
    vertical: false,
    altLabels: false,
    editable: true,
    value: null,
    items1: [{ id: 50, name: "As soon as possible (Less than 1 hour)", val: 50 }, {id: 25, name: "A quick response time (Less than 2 hours)", val: 25}, {id: 0, name: "Moderately fast (Less than 6 hours)", val: 0}],
    items2: [{id: 50, name: 'Yes (Premium only)', val: 50 }, {id: 0, name: 'No', val: 0}],
    items3: [{id: 50, name: 'Yes (Premium and Professional)', val: 50}, {id: 0, name: 'No', val: 0}],
    items4: [{id: 25, name: 'Yes (Premium only)', val: 25}, {id: 0, name: 'No', val: 0}],
    items5: [{id: 25, name: 'Extensive (Premium)', val: 25}, {id: 0, name: 'Basic', val: 0}],
    items6: [{id: 25, name: 'Yes (Premium and Professional)', val: 0}, {id: 0 , name: 'No', val: 0}],
    items7: ['Alabama','Alaska','Arizona','Arkansas','California','Colorado','Connecticut','Delaware','District of Columbia','Florida','Georgia','Hawaii','Idaho','Illinois','Indiana','Iowa','Kansas','Kentucky','Louisiana','Maine','Maryland','Massachusetts','Michigan','Minnesota','Mississippi','Missouri','Montana','Nebraska','Nevada','New Hampshire','New Jersey','New Mexico','New York','North Carolina','North Dakota','Ohio','Oklahoma','Oregon','Pennsylvania','Puerto Rico','Rhode Island','South Carolina','South Dakota','Tennessee','Texas','Utah','Vermont','Virginia','Washington','West Virginia','Wisconsin','Wyoming'],
    items8: ['1 - 10', '10 - 25', '25 - 50', '50 - 100', '100 - 500', ' 500+ '],
    questionAnswer: [],
  }
},

watch: {
  steps (val) {
    if (this.e1 > val) {
      this.e1 = val
    }
  },
  vertical () {
    this.e1 = 2
    requestAnimationFrame(() => this.e1 = 1) // Workarounds
  },
},

methods: {
  onInput (val) {
    this.steps = parseInt(val)

  },
  nextStep(n) {
    if (n === this.steps) {
      this.e1 = n
    } else {
      this.e1 = n + 1
    }
  },

submit(){

console.table(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.questionAnswer)));

  var response1 = "Premium Package";
  var response2 = "Pro Package";
  var response3 = "Essentials Package";
  var response4 = "There are questions missing, please select a valid answer";
  var response5 = "An error occured, please refresh your browser page";

    const add = (a, b) =>
                  a + b

    const sum = this.questionAnswer.reduce(add)
    console.table(sum);

  if (sum >= 50){

    window.alert(response1);
  } else if(sum <= 50 && sum >= 25) {

    window.alert(response2);
  } else if(sum < 25){

    window.alert(response3);
  }
},

addAnswer(i){  
    this.questionAnswer.push({
      questionId: i,         
    })    
},
```

}

Maybe I should use a different approach? I've also explored the possibility of searching for certain values. Like, if a user gives an answer that has a value of 50, that user should be shown the "premium package". I've also tried to do an array search using the `find()` method, but even if the value is there, it is returned false. I have a bad feeling that I'm missing something here. Maybe I need to convert to a different object type, or am I too far gone here? I've spent way too much time trying to solve this, any and all insights that would allow me to salvage this code would be very much appreciated, Thanks for your time.

Comment: You're trying to add objects to other objects.  instead you need to add `a.property + b.property`.  "property" being whatever key on the object has the value you want to sum together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to sum properties of objects inside array of objects. I write a simple example that you can apply to your own code.

```js
var obj = [
  { value: 5 },
  { value: 3 },
  { value: 2 },
  { value: 8 }
];

var sum = obj.reduce((a, b) => a + b.value, 0);

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Hello sir, thank you for this answer. Its a little clearer but now response is NaN (Not a Number) I used this code....var sum = this.questionAnswer.reduce((a, b) => a + b.val, 0);

Comment: @AlCapwned because your array (questionAnswer) might not correct (eg: some items does not contains 'val' property). Could you evaluate `console.log(questionAnswer)` and paste console output here?

Comment: @AlCapwned Can you use pastebin.com, please?

Comment: console response without JSON parse: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mW4Im.png

Comment: But it doesn't contains property named `val` which you are summing. :|

Comment: Ok...sorry...gave wrong attribute. Thank you so much for this!!! Question Answered!

Comment: hope it helps )